# Word that could not pass to application using SMS twilio long code

Tags: twilio, sms

Due to budget constraint, we are currently using Twilio ten digit number for SMS.  We would like to capture "**help**" keyword when user texts us but appears that Twilio reserves that word and send back to user as "Reply STOP to unsubscribe...".  The "**help**" word never make it back to our application.

Is there a way to resolve that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twilio Copilot (Messaging) service along with Advanced Opt-out which will allows you to customize the HELP response.

[Getting Started with Advanced Opt-Out for Messaging Services](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034798533-Getting-Started-with-Advanced-Opt-Out-for-Messaging-Services)

[Customizing Users’ Opt-in and Opt-out Experience with Advanced Opt-Out](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/advanced-opt-out)

> Twilio includes an OptOutType property in the request object sent to
>   the webhook URL configured for your Messaging Service. The value is
>   START, STOP, or HELP, depending on the incoming keyword.